# can not pass Enum type as parameter type of function

Tags: ios, enums, swift2

I am new in iOS Swift 2.

I have defined a simple function:

```
// ERROR: 'Method' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context
func sendRequest(method: Method, resource: String) -> NSDictionary {
     Alamofire.request(method, "https://httpbin.org/get")
}
```

As you see, I defined the first parameter has type `Method`, which is used by [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire). I looked into the `Method`, it is a `Enum` defined as below:

```
public enum Method: String {
    case OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, TRACE, CONNECT
}
```

Why I can not use enum type as parameter type of my function?

(The reason why I want to do this is I don't want to pass `String` type and check if String is e.g. `'get'` then use `.GET`, so, I want to directly pass the `Method` enum value to the function.)

**==== update ====**

`Method` is from [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) library, I can't change anything. Looks like it is a name conflicts. But how to get rid of this problem?

Comment: Probably a name clash with another type named `Method`.  Change the name of the enum or prefix it with the module name (`Appname.Method`)

Comment: I updated my post. `Method` is from Alamofire library.

Comment: Use `Alamofire.Method` as the type name in your function

Comment: @dan, thanks. it does work. Can you make a answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There compiler sees more than one type named `Method` (`Alamofire.Method` and `ObjectiveC.Method`) and doesn't know which one you want to use for your function.

You have to prefix the type name with the module name to tell it which one to use:

```
func sendRequest(method: Alamofire.Method, resource: String) -> NSDictionary {
     Alamofire.request(method, "https://httpbin.org/get")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Method` is ambiguous with the runtime type of the same name. I recommend selecting a different type name that does not collide with existing types.

Comment: I updated my post. `Method` is from Alamofire library, I can't change anything. How to get rid of this problem?